# Best ethernet over power adapter

Tags: ethernet

Can anyone recommend a good ethernet over power adapter? The [BiPAC 2070](http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/review/networking_wireless_voip/billion/bipac_2070_homeplug_av_200_desktop_ethernet_bridge/221239) seems to have had favorable reviews but does not seem to be widely available. Other popular devices include:

- [NetComm NP200AV](http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/review/networking_wireless_voip/netcomm/np200av/218439)
- [D-Link DHP-300](http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/review/networking_wireless_voip/d-link/dhp-300/220921)
- [NETGEAR HDXB101](http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/review/networking_wireless_voip/netgear/powerline_hd_ethernet_adapters_hdxb101/220421)

This is for a situation where network cabling and wi-fi are not viable options.

Comment: OH.  You literally mean, ethernet over power lines, versus power over ethernet.  I had an answer all written based on some PoE stuff I just finished that was amazing for a mid-size Wi-Fi site.

Comment: Product recommendation questions are off-topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 3):

I can't say that it's better or worse than the others, but I've used the NETGEAR in a personal setting and have had no trouble with them.  Throughput is good -- far better than the flaky G wifi it replaced -- and I haven't experienced any of the noise problems that some people complain of when things like vacuum cleaners are running.

Comment: I have the Netgear units as well and have had no problems with them.

Comment: Yep, positive experience with the netgear power bricks here, too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old now, and I have no direct experience, but I wanted to add I've heard they work great... *as long as you have both ends on the same circuit*.  As soon as you cross to a different circuit you're on your own.  Since modern wiring means more smaller circuits, you might not get very far.